# How do I implement a pre-created generic tree?

Tags: python

```
Main code:

import trees as trs

def main():
    while True:
        comando = input(" ")
        if not comando:
            break
        commands = comando.split(" ")

        if (commands[0] == "RP"):
            commandRP(commands, trs)

        elif(commands[0] == "RU"):
            commandRU(commands, trs)

        elif(commands[0] == "RF"):
            commandRF(commands, trs)

        elif(commands[0] == "AF"):
            commandAF(commands, trs)

        elif(commands[0] == "DF"):
            commandDF(commands, trs)
        
        elif(commands[0] == "LP"):
            commandLP(commands, trs)

        elif(commands[0] == "LU"):
            commandLU(commands, trs)

        elif(commands[0] == "LF"):
            commandLF(commands, trs)

        elif(commands[0] == "MF"):
            commandMF(commands, trs)

        elif(commands[0] == "MC"):
            commandMC(commands, trs)

        elif(commands[0] == "CC"):
            commandCC(commands, trs)

        elif(commands[0] == "LCU"):
            commandLCU(commands, trs)

        elif(commands[0] == "LFC"):
            commandLFC(commands, trs)
        
        elif(commands[0] == "LSP"):
            commandLSP(commands, trs)

        elif(commands[0] == "LMS"):
            commandLMS(commands, trs)

        elif(commands[0] == "G"):
            commandG(commands, trs)

        elif(commands[0] == "L"):
            commandL(commands, trs)

        else:
            print("Invalid Instruction")


def commandRP(commands, trs):
    data = commands[1]
    t = trs.Tree()
    t.insert(data)

def commandRU(commands, trs):
    pass

def commandRF(commands, trs):
    pass

def commandAF(commands, trs):
    pass

def commandDF(commands, trs):
    pass

def commandLP(commands, trs):
    pass

def commandLU(commands, trs):
    pass

def commandLF(commands, trs):
    pass

def commandMF(commands, trs):
    pass

def commandMC(commands, trs):
    pass

def commandCC(commands, trs):
    pass

def commandLCU(commands, trs):
    pass

def commandLFC(commands, trs):
    pass

def commandLSP(commands, trs):
    pass

def commandLMS(commands, trs):
    pass

def commandG(commands, trs):
    pass

def commandL(commands, trs):
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    t = trs.Tree()
    a = t.insert("US")
    t.insert("Patient", a)
    main()
```

Tree implementation code:

```
class TreeNode:
    def __init__(self, data, children = None, parent = None):
        self.data = data
        self.children = []
        self.parent = None

    def is_leaf(self):
        if self.children == 0:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def is_root(self):
        if self.parent == None:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    
    def add_child(self, child):
        self.parent = self
        self.children.append(child)

    def depth(self):
        if self.is_root():
            return 0
        else:
            return 1 + self.parent.depth

class Tree:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None
        self.height = 0
        self.nodes = []

    def insert(self, data, parent = None):
        if parent is not None:
            parent.add_child(data)
        else:
            if parent is None:
                self.root = data
            self.nodes.append(data)
```

What I'm trying to do is, by the time I run the code I already have a pre created **Root** with **2 childs**.

When I run the code it gives me the following error: "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'add_child'" and I can't seem to figure what's wrong.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: they are in 2 different files

Comment: This is not reproducible, it seems they need to be in two serparate files (`trs/__init__.py` and `main.py` or whatever names), and you also have a missing `from trs import Tree, TreeNode` at the start of `main.py`. Or else (better) move the test code to the `__main__` section of  the same file. Also, the `main()` at the end of your test-code is undefined, commt it out/remove it. Either way, please fix this up to be reproducible, and edit your question.

Comment: I didn't post it in its entirely earlier cause I thought it wouldn't matter for the issue. And it's 2 different files.

Comment: *"they are in 2 different files"* is not reproducible, you need to edit in the filenames (is that `trs.py` or `trs/__init__py`, because they import differently), edit in the missing `import` statement (is that `import trs` or `from trs import Tree, TreeNode`?). SO rules say you must make it reproducible, i.e. you have to make it [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Please fix it urgently. It's not our job to guess at what exact structure your code has.

Comment: Uhh, we really don't need your `if..elif` ladder on `if (commands[0] == ...)`. 'MCVE' means please just post the minimum snippet of code that is reproducible i.e. self-contained, executes, and illustrates the issue, and nothing more.

Comment: Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code.

Answer (score 0):

The code breaks differently for me when I run it. I strongly recommend you insert print statements in each method so you can see yourself what's happening. There are several bugs. How you import your tree package/module will affect things, and you haven't reproducibly shown how you do that.

`Tree.insert()` when called with `data = 'Patient'` will clobber `t.root` to the string 'Patient', instead of a child node with the string 'Patient'.